# Executing Python code using php script

Tags: php, python, apache, wampserver

I have a python code and I want to execute it from my php. I have seen all the other questions. But my problem is that I am not getting proper directory path.
My test python code is,

```
a=4
b=5
return a+b
```

I was making a small html like,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
    $result = exec("python test.py");
    echo $result;
?>  

</body>
</html>
```

I was running it from wamp server. So I put both of them in www folder. Their urls are C:\wamp\www\test.py C:\wamp\www\1.php. I have installed python in my C: drive. So what is the proper path setup?
And do I have to update my Apache server settings for python running?

Comment: That is not **python** , the given test python script is having semicolon ? `;`

Comment: First things first, try running the code manually via the command line and ensure that things are going well. I don't know python, so I can't attest to the validity of your code, but I would presume that `return` would be something that you'd do in a function, not as a script. Is there maybe an `echo` or `print` command in python?

Comment: I dont understand why not going stright forward and executing python directly ?

Comment: @anmol_upal Python uses the ; as a separator but you can also use them at the end of a line, which makes them look like a statement terminator, but this is legal only because blank statements are legal in Python -- a line that contains a semicolon at the end is two statements, the second one blank.

Comment: Actually ; does not matter. And I have removed it. @Fedey I have a project where I have to run python from php. These codes are for testing purpose to check weather the php python combination is working or not

Comment: @KevinNagurski I was thinking that if the python file result is printed in php then it should have some return value. I may not be correct thats why I am asking.

Comment: @Pritam What you are doing with the `exec` command is not *running* python from PHP, but rather asking the command line to run the python script. Neither script has any influence on the other. The python script needs to be able to run entirely within the command line before it can be executed like that.

Comment: @KevinNagurski then how can I run a python code in my website and get the result?

Comment: @Pritam you should probably look at executing python instead of PHP, sorry I don't know python, so I can't help there, but if you NEED python and all PHP is doing is acting as a conduit, you really should take PHP out of the equation. As a further aside, the `exec` command can be very dangerous (`exec('rm -rf ~/'); // please never run this`) and a fair percentage of hosting providers don't allow it.

Answer (score 1):

in your python code you must have a print not return, and in php code try to use absolute path.
**Python**

```
a=4;
b=5;
print  a+b;
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$result = exec("C:\\Python27\\python.exe C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test.py");
print_r( $result);
?>
```

or

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('C:/xampp/htdocs/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```